# Froyo - Gmail - Can you delete by message, or only by thread?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, gmail

Running on a out-of-box, unupgraded T-Mobile G2, which is running Froyo, if I'm correct.

This version of the Gmail application has a delete button, which is undocumented in their web help.

When I use it, it appears to delete the entire thread/conversation, rather than a single message. Is this the expected behavior?

UPDATE:

Found the verison number -> "Version 2.3"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it's expected behavior. I mean, the big "Delete" button in the Gmail web app tosses the whole conversation to the dust bin. You have to dig a little deeper on the individual message to delete it out of the conversation. (Also, unlike the web app there is no option to view individual messages like a classical e-mail client.)

By the way, have you downloaded the latest Gmail app from the Market? There are quite a number of significant improvements over the stock app.

Comment: It would be really nice if they added this feature though!

Comment: I couldn't find a way to get the delete button to target one message in the thread, and when you actually press the button it does say:

Comment: Don't leave us in suspense!

Comment: (eek...) Confirm Deletion -> Do you want to delete this conversation?

Comment: I updated to 2.3.2 from the market, and it still behaves the same. So I checked this as the answer.